NDK at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file
I have tried to install SDK (latest version) from Android studio, soon after running react-native run-android, i get an error telling me that "NDK at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file"
Unfortunately when i run react-native doctor, everything is green checked. An error occurred after installing react-native-screens.
I have tried to clean gradlew by navigating to the project root directory and unfortunately i get an error telling me that gradlew in not recognized as internal command from CMD

Have you checked if the mentioned folder (and the file) exists? You may need to manually download the NDK of the mentioned version using Android SDK manager.

Thanks, i solved an error by creating source.properties manually which the put its contents automatically. I also upgraded NDK version from 26.1.10909125 to the upper one then cleared gradle and rebuild the project, i think the problem was with nkd v 26.1.10909125

The solution:
Trying to upgrade ndk from v 26.1.10909125 to the upper one solved the problem.
Navigate to android folder in your project, inside it open build.gradle, change ndkVersion  to 27.0.11902837.
Or go to your ndk path and delete installed ndk and reinstall them again.

You can uninstall the ndk versions in android studio and reinstall them that does work in my case

Open Android Studio: Launch Android Studio on your machine.

Go to SDK Manager: Navigate to File > Settings (on Windows/Linux) or
Android Studio > Preferences (on macOS).

Select Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.

Select the SDK Tools Tab: Click on the SDK Tools tab at the top.

Uncheck the NDK: Find NDK (Side by Side) in the list.

Uncheck the box next to it.

Apply Changes: Click Apply or OK at the bottom.


Android Studio will uninstall the selected NDK versions.
This will uninstall, but then you have to install it again, and hopefully, that should unblock you(it does in my case) by using the latest version of NDK installed in my build.gradle
android {
    ndkVersion "27.2.12479018"
}

